# Unity C# IOS Swipe detection

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, input, swipe

In my current Game, I am detecting the swipe but the player must release their finger from the screen to register each swipe direction.  What do I need to do in order for the player to not have to lift their finger from the screen?

For example, I want the player to be able to swipe up "Which will move my player up" then swipe right "moving my player to the right" all without lifting their finger off the screen.  My current way of doing it doesn't work for this and the player has to take their finger off the screen between each swipe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use oldPositionX and newPositionX finger do detect it

```
    if ((oldPositionX - newPositionX).magnitude > minOffcetFinger)
    {
       // Some code
       oldPositionX = newPositionX;
    }
```